# Wrong round calculation and uncomplete send keys (Python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, floating-point, rounding

SO SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH OR BAD EXPLANATION. (NOOBIE)

The script should round down a value to 1 decimal and make some calculations, then send it to an input box on a website by selenium.

```
    amount_value = round(equity/price, 1)  
    if amount_value > (equity/price):            # Fix the excess
        amount_value = amount_value - 0.1        # -0.1 if the rounded is larger than original
    amount_leverage = amount_value * 5           # OUTPUT
    print(amount_leverage)
    amount.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE + Keys.BACK_SPACE + Keys.BACK_SPACE + Keys.BACK_SPACE + Keys.BACK_SPACE + Keys.BACK_SPACE + Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    amount.send_keys(amount_leverage)            # Send the output inside the input box
```

The problems are 2:

1. sometimes the calculation works and the output is 500.0, 500.5 (example) but in other cases the output is 500.000000006 (should be 1 decimal point)
2. when the output is sent to the input box it lose the dot (if it's 500.5 in the input box it writes 5005), it worked perfectly until yesterday and the input box allow decimal points.

3 BONUS. How I can replace all the backspace in the second last line and perform a CTRL+a, backspace in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you remove 0.1 if the value was rounded up.

This causes minor miscalculations to happen because of how computers handle floating point numbers. For example, enter this into a python interpreter:

```
>>> 0.4 - 0.1
```

And you will receive:

```
0.30000000000000004
```

I recommend using floor to round down to one decimal place like this:

```
math.floor(NUMBER*10)/10
```

Without more information on the HTML code behind the input on the site, I cannot determine why the decimal place isn't being inputted correctly. Please post the form itself.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I've resolved the first problem calling another round after the subtraction, and the second deleting cache and geckodriver logs. However probably I will implement math.floor